# How to run a Google adsence account on local IP address

Tags: jquery, html, adsense

How to run a Google adsence account on local IP address ?

This works perfect on local server but i want to run on IP address.

Here is the IP address:- http://112.196.9.214:8021
on Index page I have placed google adsence  code.

**Google Adsence Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">     
               </script>
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
                 google-ad-client="ca-pub-1672130412430902"
                 google-ad-slot="5663592879"
                google-ad-width=120
                 google-ad-height=240
                 google-ad-format="auto">
            </ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please not refer any google link send to me , I can not find any solution.